# Reading browser cookies lambda proxy java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, cookies, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I know it is possible to get a cookie in lambda proxy. I can't find any sources on retrieving the cookies except in node.js (but it isn't in the same format). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Cookie can be set up in the response headers. Return as a response something like this:

```
{
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {'Set-Cookie': 'key=val'},
    body: 'Some response'
}
```

To read cookies you need to check the request header. It's provided in [the event from API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https.html). It's either `event.headers.Cookie`.

Comment: Sorry I meant 'get' a cookie

Comment: @Meerfallthedewott update. Also, it may be useful to check this guide https://faragta.com/aws-api-gateway/pass-cookie-values-from-api-gateway.html it simplifies access to cookies from the event.

Comment: faragta.com/aws-api-gateway/… the options described here aren't available for lambda proxy and I can't find event.headers.Cookie in my context